# How to test JavaScripts without to delete the `test` database data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2, cucumber-rails-1.3.0, rspec-rails-2.8.1 and capybara-1.1.2. I would like to use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) in order to test JavaScripts, but without to delete the `test` database data each time I run the `cucumber` command line in my Terminal window. That is, if I state a feature like the following:

```
Feature: ...

  @javascript
  Scenario: ...
```

JavaScript is tested as well as expected. However, after the test has run, the `test` database data is deleted and I must seed again that database in order to properly run new tests.

I read the [Official Documentation](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) and the text present in the `ROOT_APP/features/support/env.rb` file (it seems that I installed all required Ruby gems - see below for more information about the Gemfile that I am using) but I didn't understand how to avoid to delete the database data and how to configure Cucumber and Capybara gems so to properly work with Selenium.

**What should I make?**

*Note I*: I would like to make the above because  *I would like to have the same `test` database data when I "test"/"run" Scenarios*.

*Note II*: In order to seed data in the `test` database (my application needs that data to work), I add the following code in the `RAILS_ROOT_PATH/lib/tasks/cucumber.rake` file and I run the `rake db:test:prepare` command line from the Terminal window.

```
namespace :db do
  namespace :test do
    task :prepare => :environment do
      Rake::Task["db:seed"].invoke
    end
  end
end
```

---

In the `ROOT_APP/features/support/env.rb` file I tried to uncomment one and both of the following blocks of code (*BTW*: I never changed the original file auto-generated by the `cucumber-rails` gem, so it is the default one), but after running tests it still deletes the `test` database data.

```
#   Before('@no-txn,@selenium,@culerity,@celerity,@javascript') do
#     # { :except => [:widgets] } may not do what you expect here
#     # as tCucumber::Rails::Database.javascript_strategy overrides
#     # this setting.
#     DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
#   end
#
#   Before('~@no-txn', '~@selenium', '~@culerity', '~@celerity', '~@javascript') do
#     DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
#   end
```

---

Gemfile excerpt:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem "rspec-rails"
end

group :test do
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'capybara'
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this same problem, and managed to fix it by changing the following line in `ROOT_APP/features/support/env.rb`

from

```
Cucumber::Rails::Database.javascript_strategy = :truncation
```

to

```
Cucumber::Rails::Database.javascript_strategy = :transaction
```

Hope this helps...